How to uniquely identify uprobes when targeting multi threaded applications
I have an eBPF application that hooks malloc and mmap (via uprobes). The application targets a specific target application and as a result I do PID filtering using bpf_get_ns_current_pid_tgid (container aware).
Upon entry to malloc or mmap I get some information about the calls and store that in a map for later retrieval by the exit eBPF program. The exit eBPF program looks up the entry via the constant key, adds some more data and sends to user land. Lastly, it deletes the entry in the map.
Currently I just use an integer key to the map since I always expected that there could only ever be one call running at any given time. However, in a multithreaded target application, I suppose you can have multiple threads call malloc and as a result I (think) I can have interspersed invocations of my eBPF entry/exit programs. I.e., the following call sequence: malloc, malloc, malloc, exit, exit, exit (or other combinations). As a result, my current key'ng strategy doesn't work since it assumes one call and one entry in the map.
As such, I'm interested in knowing if anyone has encountered this before and what key'ng strategy the used in light of multi threaded apps.
As a side note and not directly related to multi-threaded applications, there is another scenario in a single threaded application that conceptually shows the same problem. Sometimes when calling malloc with a fairly large allocation size, malloc internally invokes mmap for efficiency reasons. We now have a similar problem where the malloc is followed by mmap using a single entry in the map to store information related to both calls (which obviously fails).
I looked at keying on pid/tgid as is done in many eBPF programs (bpf_get_current_pid_tgid), but in my experiments, multiple threads in the target application will have the same pid/tgid when viewed from eBPF land. In other words, if I were to key off of pid/tgid I would still have conflicts in the map since it's the same.

What sort of applications are you tracing? I would have expected bpf_get_current_pid_tgid to work in most cases. How exactly did you use bpf_get_current_pid_tgid?

Any application really. Let's use malloc as an example, I call bpf_get_current_pid_tgid upon entry to the malloc uprobe. I then get the PID by: pid = pidtgid >> 32. Next, I create temporary storage:

Any application really. Use malloc as an example, I call bpf_get_current_pid_tgid on entry to malloc. Then get the PID by: pid = pidtgid >> 32. Next, I store the allocation event in the hashmap: if (bpf_map_update_elem(&argsHashMap, &pidtid, event, BPF_ANY) != 0) . In the exit malloc uprobe I then fetch that entry from the hashmap event = (struct ResourceInformation*) bpf_map_lookup_elem(&argsHashMap, &pidtid); and send it over the ring buffer to userland. If the target application is multi-threaded, two concurrent mallocs occur at the same time and the hashmap gets clobbered.

I think that's because you're retrieving the TGID with your 32 shift, not the PID. Maybe try to index the map with the full 64-bits value from bpf_get_current_pid_tgid.
